# Jquery to load content into div

Tags: jquery, popup, load

Hey there, I would like to load an html page into a div using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popupContent").load("aeffect.html");

    //Close property
$("a.close").click(function(){
        $("#popupContainer").empty();

        });
});
```

My html from the calling page is:

```
<div id="popupContent"></div>
```

What I would like to do, is when `aeffect.html` is loaded into the div, that it also writes the code from `aeffect.html` into the body of the calling page so that the end resulton the calling page would read as follows:

```
<div id="popupContent">
    <div class="projectPopup" id="aeffect">
    <a class="close">Close &times;</a>
    <img src="/img/aeffect_popup.jpg" width="500" height="729" alt="" />
    <p class="description">Description</p></div>
</div>
```

My problem is resulting because I am trying to make `aeffect.html` disappear once the user hits `close`. I figured I could just have it empty the DIV, but there is nothing to empty…

Comment: I would like the `aeffect.html` content to be loaded into the `popupContent`, so that the code form the aeffect.html page will be called out and loaded into the calling page.

Comment: I haven't tested it. But what you describe is exactly what the .load method should do. What's the problem? Any error messages?

Comment: no error messages, but when the load function is running, it doesnt extract the code from aeffect.html into the div, so when aeffect.html loads, the html from the calling page still looks like:

    <div id="popupContent"></div>

Comment: @Anthony, I assume you're using Firebug to check the source of the page, not "View Source"?

Comment: Did you wrap the .load call in a `jQuery(document).ready(...)` block?

Comment: Yeah, it's all working fine. The reason I am asking is because I have a close button and would like to somehow revert the div back to empty so that aeffect disappears.

Comment: 1. As Aziz asked: do you use Firebug to view the HTML source?
2. Do you have an event bound to the close button (`<a class="close">` I guess)? If you did that in aeffect.html then it won't be there in the calling page as jQuery IMHO can't load events via the .load method.

Comment: Are you making a cross-site call?

Comment: Yeah I am using Firebug to check the code.
@Objektivs, yeah I guess it would be a cross-site call… if you could epxlain that though? I am calling a function from the calling page to close the div on the calling page itself, however that function is located on the aeffect.html page…

Answer (score 2):

(You're missing a closing div, I think, on #aeffect.)

```
$('#popupContent').load('page.htm #aeffect')
```

The first selector is the target container. The load method takes the page followed by the selector within that page that you want.

I'm not sure about loading pages from other sites though.

Let me know if that works for you.
Scott

Check out the jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) for fine tuning. You can pass parameters to the page if it is a post and you can use a callback to populate the div for a smoother experience.